# Container won't connect to redis container

Tags: docker, go, redis

I'm trying to connect to my redis container from my container running a Go server but the the connection keeps getting refused despite what appears to be a correct setup in my docker-compose.yml:

## Go

```golang
redisClient = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Network:  "tcp",
        Addr:     "redis_server:6379",
        Password: "", // no password set
        DB:       0,  // use default DB
    })
```

## docker-compose

```
version: "0.1"
services:
  redis_server:
    image: "redis"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  lambda_server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:50051"
    links:
      - redis_server
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but you should add a `depends_on` to your `lambda_server` which references `redis_server`.

Comment: @Jesse how is this different from links? From the wording I assume that it won't allow the lambda_server to run if redis_server does not run

Comment: Ah, that's right. I missed that piece when reading the docs.

Comment: oftopic: why you use old version of compose syntax(version: "0.1") ? try to change to version: '3.5'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Redis doesn’t allow remote connections. You can connect to the Redis server only from 127.0.0.1 (localhost) - the machine where Redis is running.

Replace `bind 127.0.0.1` with `bind 0.0.0.0` in the /etc/redis/redis.conf file.

then run `sudo service redis-server restart` to restart the server.

Use the following command to verify that redis is listening on all interfaces on port 6379:

```
ss -an | grep 6379
```

You should see something like below. 0.0.0.0 means all IPv4 addresses on the machine.

```
tcp  LISTEN 0   128   0.0.0.0:6379   0.0.0.0:*
tcp  LISTEN 0   128      [::]:6379      [::]:*
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, you might need to check any firewalls that might block the access.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and that was related to address binding. In redis configuration file, /etc/redis/redis.conf, find the line having prefix `bind`. Usually, this line contains `bind 127.0.0.1`. This means, only from the same host as the redis server (redis server container in your case) client connections are accepted.

You need to add the host name or the host ip of your client container in this bind deffinition line, if you want the client connection be accepted.

```
bind 127.0.0.1 <client-ip or client-hostname>
```

Another way to achieve this is binding any address by,

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

In either case, tou need to restart the redis server with the changed `redis.conf`.

### Update

From [redis.conf](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf) file, we can see the followings:

> ```
> # By default, if no "bind" configuration directive is specified, Redis listens
> # for connections from all the network interfaces available on the server.
> # It is possible to listen to just one or multiple selected interfaces using
> # the "bind" configuration directive, followed by one or more IP addresses.
> #
> # Examples:
> #
> # bind 192.168.1.100 10.0.0.1
> # bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
> #
> # ~~~ WARNING ~~~ If the computer running Redis is directly exposed to the
> # internet, binding to all the interfaces is dangerous and will expose the
> # instance to everybody on the internet. So by default we uncomment the
> # following bind directive, that will force Redis to listen only into
> # the IPv4 loopback interface address (this means Redis will be able to
> # accept connections only from clients running into the same computer it
> # is running).
> #
> # IF YOU ARE SURE YOU WANT YOUR INSTANCE TO LISTEN TO ALL THE INTERFACES
> # JUST COMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE.
>
> bind 127.0.0.1
> ```

You can see that the bind address is 127.0.0.1 by default. So, for your case, either you can specify the address or comment the line.

Comment: I think this configuration is already made in redis image. In my project i use redis image without changes in configs and connect from another container works fine

Comment: @RyabchenkoAlexander I have updated the answer telling that the address is 127.0.0.1 by default.